# Browser not saving cookie in storage

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, cookies, cors

I have a spring mvc backend at `http://localhost:8080/` and a angular frontend at `http://localhost:4200`. I am sending a cookie from backend to frontend but it isn't being saved by the browser.

I have configured cors in following way:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
    }
```

**And cors is working fine as I am able to do api request from frontend to backend.**

I am sending a cookie in response:

Cookie code:

```
Cookie refreshCookie = new Cookie("x-refresh", "my-token");
            refreshCookie.setPath("/");
            refreshCookie.setMaxAge(2 * 60);
            refreshCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            response.addCookie(refreshCookie);
```

Following header is sent in response:

```
Set-Cookie: x-refresh=my-token; Max-Age=120; Expires=Sun, 24 Sep 2023 06:27:26 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

My problem is the cookie isn't being saved in the browser storage and I also can't see it in devtools.

Why isn't cookie being saved in browser/

Comment: How are you issuing the request whose response contains that `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: Can you try returning request `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `withCredentials: true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. I thought I was sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in my request but that wasn't the case.

After fixing my code and actually sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the request, browser is saving the cookie and everything is working now.

### Solution

Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the request header: